# Casting LIVE HLS on Chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast, http-live-streaming

I've made an application to cast HLS streams on a Chromecast.

It works well with VOD streams (non live), but it's not with a LIVE stream.

So here is my question : Can Chromecast read LIVE streams ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can and many chromecast application already do. You may want to use our [MPL library](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/), or use your own player. You may need to write a custom receiver if the Styled/Default receiver is not doing what you need.

Comment: ...and maybe consider CORS for HLS streams.